# Need to replace value of an attribute in XML file using Xpath

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath, replace, web-config

Below is the content of source/destine XML(Web.Config) file, in which I have to replace value of an attribute. This needs to be done for several config files, so need your help to get this done using powershell. I did try with the codes for replacing strings which are available in stackOverFlow- but dint make it..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
-->

<configuration>
<connectionStrings>

<add name="PrcEntities"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
   connectionString="Server=DDD05DB01,63518;Database=BBBDB001;Trusted_Connection=true;multipleactiveresultsets=true;Pooling=false"/>

<add name="CoreItemContext"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
 connectionString="Server=DDD15DB03,63520;Database=BBBDB002;Trusted_Connection=true;multipleactiveresultsets=true;Pooling=true"/>

</connectionStrings>
..

..

....

</configuration>
```

This is my Powershell code to query the attribute named "ConnectionString" from above XML file

```
$Path = "C:\Ps\Web.config" 
$con="connectionString"   
[xml]$Types = Get-Content $Path 
Select-Xml -Xml $Types -XPath "//add" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node|Select-Object name,$con | Format-List
```

Which will result in :

*name             : PrcEntities*
connectionString : Server=DDD05DB01,63518;Database=BBBDB001;Trusted_Connection=true;
multipleactiveresultsets=true;Pooling=false

*name             : CoreItemContext*
connectionString : Server=DDD15DB03,63520;Database=BBBDB002;Trusted_Connection=true;
multipleactiveresultsets=true;Pooling=true

Now, I want to replace the value of attribute '**connectionString**' with details like:
Server=DBD05DB01,63518;Database=DDBDB001;Trusted_Connection=true;multipleactiveresultsets=true;Pooling=false in both the places(PrcEntities & CoreItemContext)

This change should be saved to same source file. Please help me on this!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$path = "D:\Web.Config"
[xml]$xml = Get-Content $path 

$xml.configuration.connectionStrings.add | Foreach-Object {
    $_.connectionString = 'Server=DBD05DB01,63518;Database=DDBDB001;Trusted_Connection=true;multipleactiveresultsets=true;Pooling=false'
}

$xml.Save($path)
```